# Diffuser's hadamard logic in equal superposition with negative phases

Tags: quantum-gate, grovers-algorithm, hadamard

This is with reference to the question here:

[How to understand intuitively the Grover diffusion operator?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14933/how-to-understand-intuitively-the-grover-diffusion-operator)

Overall it makes sense on how H^n of the diffuser logic creates the |000..0> from an equal superposition. However, the input wouldn't be equal superposition, right?  As in, the oracle would have flipped the phases of the specific state of interest, and we will be having one of the terms to be -1, right? So, how should the Hadmard's action on this state be interpreted? It won't be |000..0>s right?