# How does applying Z gate to $|0\rangle$ change the phase of other states during reflection about $|s\rangle$ in Grover algorithm in Qiskit textbook

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, grovers-algorithm

I am trying to understand the Reflection Gate - **Us** explained for 2 qubits in the qiskit textbook. In the explanation it is mentioned that first Hadamard gate is applied to change the state $|s\rangle$ to $|0\rangle$ then a circuit adds negative phase to all the states orthogonal to $|s\rangle$ and this is done by applying 2 $Z$ (one each on both the qubits) gates followed by a controlled $Z$. I am confused about this because once $|s\rangle$ goes to $|0\rangle$ there won't be any superposition so $Z$ gates won't do anything at all because the effect of $Z$ gates on computational basis is to change $|1\rangle$ to $-|1\rangle$. Can someone please explain. This question is different from other questions asked so please do not link it to other questions.

Comment: Related question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15766/why-does-grovers-algorithm-rotate-around-000-0-rangle/15838#15838

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell:
The key fact to remember is that what you called the reflection gate is only applied *after the oracle*. Therefore, the state is not $|s\rangle$ anymore.

---

Detailed answer:

To show in more detail what's going on we can calculate a concrete example.
In general, Grover's algorithm apply the Grover operator $Q$ defined as
$$
Q = H^{\otimes n}S_0 H^{\otimes n} S_f
$$
where $H$ is the Hadamard gate, $S_0 = 2|0\rangle^{\otimes n}\langle 0|^{\otimes n} - \mathbb I$ is a reflection about the $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$
state and $S_f$ is the oracle. Sometimes we group the first three operations and call it "diffusion" because it equals a reflection about the maximally superposed state:
$$
Q = S_{+} S_f
$$
with the diffusion operator $S_+ = 2|+\rangle^{\otimes n}\langle +|^{\otimes n} - \mathbb I$.

In the standard formulation of Grover's algorithm, we initialize a maximally superposed state and apply $Q$ a specific number of times $p$ to amplify the amplitude of the solution bitstring:
$$
Q^p H^{\otimes n} |0\rangle^{\otimes n}.
$$
If you know the number of solutions you can calculate $p$, otherwise we usually apply different powers of $Q$, measure, and check if the output is a solution.

Let's look at your particular example to see that the diffusion operator really amplifies the solution state. I've attached that as notes, since the math takes a bit long to TeX

[image]

*Sidenote: you can also use different operations than $H^{\otimes n}$ to for the general amplitude amplification algorithm.*

Comment: [Texed version](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13314/8746) of the decomposition of Grover's diffusion operator

Comment: Thanks for explaining